# WPF Hittest NEXT to tabitem not working

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, hittest

I have a problem regarding hittesting in WPF. I created a custom `WindowChrome` to make tabheaders overflow into the Chrome. But I'n having a problem regarding hittests.

When I try to drag the window without opening a tab the hittest works:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI6XA.png

But as soon as i open a tab it does not hittest on the chrome anymore:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Nil.png

I basically have a grid containing the Chrome on top and below that the `TabControl`. Both are in `Grid.Row = "0"` and the `TabControl` has `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" 
 Background="{x:Null}" 
 Grid.RowSpan="2"`.

I tries searching all over google but could not find a solution to this problem. Could someone point me in the right direction?

It seems that the tabitems create a background next to them that is Transparent instead of `x:Null` thus making it fail the hittest, is there a way to make that background `x:Null` or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can map out the `Background` with this:

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem">
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
</Style>
```

Put that to your `Window.Resources`. Though it's a bit unclear what you're trying to accomplish with this: your tab items will be only selectable when you click the "text" on them, otherwise it's going to hit the windows chrome now.

Comment: I want to be able to click the complete header and still select it... The problem is that if I click next to the header I cannnot use the WindowChrome. So basically the space next to the header needs to be hittested but I'll try this first!

Comment: And by "does not work" you mean what? Nothing changed? Get snoop, and check if the background actually got `x:Null` or not.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by looking around in the snoop. I found out that I needed to edit the TabPanel in the TabControl. By adding the following code in the TabControl.Resources I fixed the problem:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"></Setter>
       <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
</Style>
```

Thanks for the help though!